# Crystal Reports: How can a not on-demand subreport be displayed as a link in the main report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am struggling to fix a subreport where data is obtained at the point when the main report is generated and the subreport to be displayed as a link, similar to an on demand subreport.

The issue that I have if I use a non on demand subreport is that it cannot be represented as a link, it is displayed inside the main report. As well  as an on demand report is not suitable to my case because the data is retrieved when the subreport is opened.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take the another header for subreport and also drilldown the Header and on the Suppress formula write the formula `Drilldowngrouplevel = 0` and for the Sub Report take the another detail section and on the supress formula write the formula `Drilldowngrouplevel = 0`.

This will definitely work, because I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a group level to the subreport and add a single line into the group header?

This will mean you will have to drill down twice to get the data though.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. 

Unfortunately, the subreport should have report headers, also the link to the subreport should not be displayed when the subreport is opened.

Comment: If that is the case it may not be possible, or at least exactly as you want it to work. There may be someone who can come up with a work-around though.